# how to build a node server, with jobs ,the can run certain task at a particular time

Tags: node.js

I am building a scraper based node server , how do i get the server to run a function that scrape's the website at a particular time of day , ideally morning afternoon and evening,

The idea i have , it use `set Timeout`, but  am hoping theres a standard way of doing this or library that does this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a scheduler, this is exactly what you need. here.. I'll link you to one:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule

source: googled 'node.js cron'

Comment: :>*) awesome , cron so that its called